# How to check the feature is available in HTML attributes? - Browser Support

Tags: html

I want to know whether the feature or functionality is available or not in the HTML attributes. 
   For an example the "orientation" functionality is not available in screen(Safari).

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/)

Comment: Can i Use what it is?

Comment: Compatibility charts for various languages

Answer (score 0):

I always use https://www.browserstack.com/mobile-browser-emulator to test websites.

You can find the attributes here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp in the HTML tags list and the browser support is about 3/4 way down the page.

Please edit your question if this does not answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean if can you test for certain functionality using (for example) javascript, then I'd say it's pretty much impossible. There are some projects that try to make older browsers compatible with some new features such as [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

I usually use [www.caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com) to find which browsers support which functionality. Most current versions of browsers support a wide range of functionality. If you are supporting older browsers (something like IE6 or IE7) I'd suggest testing with virtual machines and checking on [www.caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com) for newer features such as pseudo elements, viewport, etc.

Regarding orientation, for Safari on OSX I'd understand it not supporting it. There is no tablet or phone running OSX so you would never have to deal with orientation. Windows and it's browsers on the other hand run on the Surfaces so could have an orientation. You'd have to add some error handling and a fallback for OSX Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answer, After analysis I found the solution
ex :

```
 if ("orientation" in window.screen){
     console.log("Orientation feature available ")
   }else{
     console.log("Orientation feature not  available ")
   }
```